# Create MappingTemplate for DynamoDb GetItem to retrieve by primary key through Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am getting an http 404 from dynamodb, and page not found web page when I make this call.

[image]

I am using API gateway to interface directly with DynamoDB.

```
{
    "TableName": "mytable",
    "Key" :{
        "IntakeId" :{
            "S": "$input.params('intakeId')"
        }
    }
}
```

I run my test and I get this in the logs:

```
Mon Sep 27 00:45:44 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
    "TableName": "mytable",
    "Key" :{
        "IntakeId" :{
            "S": "BA22df4"
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to search this way:

[image]

this is my actual response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Page Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>Page Not Found</body>
</html>
```

I am able to save items, just not retrieve them.

I get the same result when I add the sort key:

```
{
    "TableName": "mytable",
    "Key": {
        "IntakeId": {
            "S": "BA22df4"
        },
        "Email" : {
            "S": ""
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
}
```